# Print a word document without changing the default printer

Tags: java, printing, awt, rtf

I have to print a RTF document created with MS Office Word without changing the default printer. 
I have found a code with Jacob but it uses the "ActivePrinter" who change the default printer.

How to print a word document without changing the default printer?

Comment: Did you try `Desktop.getDesktop.print(File)`?

Comment: nop but he use the default printer ? i wanna choose my printer

Comment: What happened when you *tried it?*

Comment: he open word and try to print it with the default printer

Comment: Is it an option to change it , print and change back?

Comment: Yes there is an option but it's not what i want it's crucial to not change the default printer